# Cordova / Phonegap - iOS Filesystem custom root path iosExtraFilesystems is not working

Tags: ios, cordova, filesystems

I'm using cordova 3.4 with the org.apache.cordova.file on iOS (last version 1.3.1).

I want to store data in the Library/NoCloud directory, i've found that in the doc we should set this variables in config.xml :

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library-nosync" />
```

But it's not working, it gives me a filesystem root in Library/files , and i can't move to the NoCloud directory because we can't get the parent of the root Library/files.

Is someone struggling with this issue as well ? Have you successfully used the iosExtraFilesystems var ?

I'm trying to upgrade cordova but i have other issues when doing it.. i will post further progress.

UPDATE:

Not working with cordova 3.5, 3.6 either, i've created an issue on the jira tracker of apache: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7687

Thanks

Thibault

Comment: I think this is a file permission issue. not in iOS but in Cordova. Please let me show the full path from iosPersistentFileLocation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, here is the full path where the filesystem is open: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/13E9EA83-94A2-4950-811E-E491AC176A78/Library/files/

Comment: ok all files or directory above Library is not accessible for your app. but i do not work with Cordova so wait for the response from apache.

Comment: yep, but i should be able to open a filesystem at Library/NoCloud . I don't want to open something above Library.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Use resolveLocalFileSystemURL rather than requestLocalFileSystem

The easiest way to do this (since v1.2.0) is with the `cordova.file.dataDirectory` property. It should be a path to the library-nosync directory. You can use it in conjunction with `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` to get a directory entry object that you can create files in.

Something like this should work:

```
resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(entry) {
    console.log("Success! Got a DirectoryEntry");
    // Do more things with `entry` here
}, function(error) {
    console.error("Something bad happened, and we didn't get a DirectoryEntry");
});
```

#### Some other notes

To clarify the two settings that you mentioned in your question:

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
```

This preference just tells the File plugin that, by default, the `PERSISTENT` file system should store files under the device's `Library` directory. Without that setting, the default is the location used by previous Cordova versions, the `Documents` directory. Regardless, the Library filesystem is available to your application (as long as you haven't disabled it with the next setting)

```
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library-nosync" />
```

The `iosExtraFilesystems` preference tells the File plugin which file system roots, in addition to the defaults (temporary and persistent,) to install. By default, it is set to the string

```
"library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root"
```

This already includes `library-nosync`, so you shouldn't have to add it. In fact, setting it the way you did actually *removes* the other file system roots from your application.

Comment: no sure how i've missed the resolveLocalFileSystemURL in the documentation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: note that the second method won't work because you'll be in Library/files , and won't be able to go to Library/NoCloud

Comment: Absolutely right; I forgot that that change had been made; I'll remove that section.

Answer (score 0):

All credit for this answer goes to Wei Li: https://github.com/weili-feedhenry/dotfiles/issues/1 , and you should read his post on cordova file system plugin: http://web.archive.org/web/20160731021013/http://www.feedhenry.com/several-ways-avoid-problems-cordova-file-api-mobile-apps

Apparently the File API doc is not up to date, in order to retrieve the file system you wanted, you need to change the request file system type in requestFileSystem call.
For example:

```
window.requestFileSystem(3, 0, function(fs){
  alert("dataDirectory = " + cordova.file.dataDirectory);
  alert("root = " + fs.root.toURL());
  fs.root.getFile("test.txt", {create: true, exclusive: true});

}, function(){
  alert("failed to get file system”)
});
```

notice that the file system type in the above call is “3” - given that you only added the following preferences in the config.xml file:

If you change the value of iosExtraFilesystems, you may need to adjust the value of the request type accordingly.

Comment: did a pull request on github for the doc: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/pull/82